# How to preg_replace between two characters, erasing comment lines?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use preg_replace to remove commented code in some css styling that's coming through php from a database. If it's better to use srt_replace or some other function please let me know how to do it.

I want to delete the commented code in:

```
/*here is some commented code*/
background: #AAA;
/*here is some commented code*/
```

My string of the above code is in $spiderman:

```
$ironman = preg_replace("//*(.*?)/*/Uis","",$spiderman);
```

How can I get $ironman to be just

```
background: #AAA;
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following preg_replace statement with non-greedy flag

```
   echo $ironman = preg_replace("/\/\*(.*)\*\//Uis","",$spiderman);
```